# Undefined behaviour while printing just initialized variables

Tags: c, initialization

I have recently started learning `C` programming. As part of exercises I have used the following program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()    {

    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    a = 350 ;

    if (a >= 400)  {

        b = 800 ;
        c = 500 ;

    }

    printf("%d %d\n", b,c);
    return 0;
}
```

For `a = 350` I am getting `32767 0` as output.
For `a = 401` I was getting expected output.

Please help me with the associated issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `b` and `c` will be initialized only `if (a >= 400)`. You have `a = 350 ;`. How can you expect that condition to be true?

Comment: Without some form of assignment (initialization or direct assignment) even *evaluating* `b` and `c` as this does invokes *undefined behavior* when `a < 400`. I.e. there is no definitive result. No matter what you *get* for output, there is no definitive characteristic for why *those* values were printed because they were obtained without your programming executing definitive behavior in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

There is nothing unexpected about this. If `a=350`, then your variables b and c are not initialized; thus they contain "random information"; whence when printing them out you get garbage. That was probably the goal of your exercise.

**edit** In a little more detail:

```
int b;
```

b now contains garbage; since you don't assign a value to `b`; it just contains the value that was accidentally present in memory when you allocate this space. If you do:

```
b = 800;
```

Now b contains the value 800... (but since when a=350 you don't get in this part of the code; the value of b remains undefined)

Answer (score 0):

Let's make it more easy

```
int main()    
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    a = 350 ;
    if (350 >= 400)  
    {

        b = 800 ;
        c = 500 ;
    }
    printf("%d %d\n", b,c);
    return 0;
}
```

instead using a variable just imagine i am using value 
Now 350 is less than 400 so it will not come inside if 
that's  why b , c is uninitialized but they having `garbage value`
that's why you getting undefined behavior SO EASY IT IS

Answer (score 0):

Variables b and c will get initialized to their respective values only when the 'if' condition gets satisfied ie a>=400 , for the rest of conditions (when a < 400) output will be some garbage values for b and c.

Answer (score 0):

In your code b and c are declared but not initialized.
un-initialized automatic or local variables will have garbage values.
so it is good practice to initialize local/automatic variables when you declare.